# Simple Product to Virtual Product Change?

Tags: configurable-product

If we have created a simple product in Magento but it was supposed to be a virtual product, is that a simple fix on the back end?

We created a large number of courses that do not require shipping and have no physical product.  Would a simple query to correct this and rewrite be possible?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Not on the backend, Magento wont allow you to change it from backend. Instead,

Run this command on DB

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET type_id='virtual' WHERE entity_id=xxx
```

Where xxx is the product id

Query is same for both **Magento 1** and **Magento 2**

Answer (score 2):

Just edit the product in admin and set `This item has no weight` and save.

https://nimb.ws/8vm7dc

It is automatically changed to virtual product.